Linux Desktop Search Program
Looking for a Linux program to locate files on an external drive.
There are command line programs like grep. Recoll is a GUI option.
Is there anything like Copernicus?

Can you add to your question the features of Copernicus you want?

Previewing the file, for one. Full-text file search, not just the name of the file. Restricting results to a particular file extension or creation date. The more options make it more likely to find the file. Copernicus is just one of the desktop search programs that does this; there's X1 for Windows, HoudahSpot for Mac.

Thanks.  Can you add the details to the question, please?

You could try DocFetcher.

it's like grep
it has GUI
it works with fulltext searches
it can restrict files based on e.g. extension


Does it index ntfs drives? Because there's a Windows version, I'd think it would, but I can't find anything in the FAQ.

Faster than looking in the docs would be downloading and trying. It may differ per system.

In Linux Mate desktop using caja file manager.  Switch caja to display external drive (assuming it is mounted) and run search command in caja.

search command as in grep, or find? Looking for something more like Copernicus, or Houdah Spot (Mac).

Also caja's search command isn't recursive, this is a better mate-specific tool: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mate-search-tool.1.html
